# How to initialize an array in test bench in VHDL?

Tags: arrays, vhdl

In the following code, the main problem is that the array is not getting initialized by the testbech.

My main purpose is to design the following unit which reads the address and outputs the instructions. The main input "INSTRUCTION_ADRESS" is an array which contains both the address and its contents.

[image]

Any comments will be greatly valued.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

PACKAGE MIPS_PACKAGE is

    type INSTRUCTION_ARRAY is array (0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

end PACKAGE MIPS_PACKAGE;


    -- INSTRUCTION MEMORY --
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned."+";

    use work.MIPS_PACKAGE.all;

    entity INSTRUCTION_MEMORY is
            port(

                PCSrc : in STD_LOGIC;
                PC_EXT : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);

                INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS : in    INSTRUCTION_ARRAY;  
                INSTRUCTION     : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)

                );
    end INSTRUCTION_MEMORY;

    architecture INST_MEM of INSTRUCTION_MEMORY is

           Signal PC: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0):="00000000000000000000000000000100";
            Signal PC_ADD4: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0):=X"00000000";        

    begin

            INSTRUCTION <= INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS(to_integer(unsigned(PC))); -- INSTRUCTION MEMORY
            PC_ADD4 <= PC + X"4"; -- ADD 4

            MUX_PC: process(PCSrc)

                begin
                    if( PCSrc = '0') then
                        PC <= PC_ADD4; 
                    else
                        PC <= PC_EXT;
                    end if;
                end process MUX_PC; 


    end INST_MEM;

    ----------
    --TESTBENCH

    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

    use work.MIPS_PACKAGE.all;

    entity INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_tb is
    end;

    architecture bench of INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_tb is

      component INSTRUCTION_MEMORY
            port(
                PCSrc : in STD_LOGIC;
                PC_EXT : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
                INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS : in    INSTRUCTION_ARRAY;  
                    INSTRUCTION     : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
                );
      end component;

      signal PCSrc: STD_LOGIC;
      signal PC_EXT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
      signal TestMemory: INSTRUCTION_ARRAY;
      signal INSTRUCTION: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0) ;

    begin

      uut: INSTRUCTION_MEMORY port map ( PCSrc               => PCSrc,
                                         PC_EXT              => PC_EXT,
                                         INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS => TestMemory,
                                         INSTRUCTION         => INSTRUCTION );

      stimulus: process
      begin

        -- Put initialisation code here

    PCSrc  <= '0';
    PC_EXT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";    
    TestMemory(0)   <= "10001100000000010000000000000000";  
    wait for 1 ns;

    PCSrc  <= '0';
    PC_EXT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000"; 
    TestMemory(4)   <= "10001100000000100000000000000001"; 
    wait for 1 ns;

    PCSrc  <= '0';
    PC_EXT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    TestMemory(8)   <= "00000000001000101000000000100000";  

    PCSrc  <= '0';
    PC_EXT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    TestMemory(12)  <= "00000010000000011000100000100000";  
    wait for 1 ns;

    PCSrc  <= '0';
    PC_EXT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    TestMemory( 16 )  <= "10101100000100000000000000000011";  
    wait for 5 ns;

        -- Put test bench stimulus code here

        wait;
      end process;


    end;
```

Comment: INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS is an array, I defined it in the package on top.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize the memory? Are you designing for FPGA or ASIC? Or just simulation?

Comment: How did you instantiate your memory. I know that macros from either Xilinx and Altera comes with generic for ram init values. Also it possible to pass a file to thoes same memories during simulation.

Comment: can you attach a copy of the simulation waveform here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just ran your code through Vivado and in this simulator, the array does get initialized exactly as it should: 
[image: Waveform screencapture]

Notice the TestMemory waveform changing every nanosecond, just as expected. Since you never initialized the whole array, the other values stay `'U'`, of course.

Now, you can see instruction only changes after 2ns, but that has nothing to do with the array not being initialized. This is because `MUX_PC: process(PCSrc)` only has `PCSrc` in its sensitivity list, which means the process will only execute once `PCSrc` actually changes. This is most likely not the desired behaviour(that would mean your `PC` could only increment when `PCSrc` changes). To solve this problem, add a clock to your design and design a synchronous process.